# d3.js pie chart fails to load data once inside angularjs directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

So, for the life of me, I can not figure out why this chart won't function properly inside of an angularjs directive. If I take the same code and post it outside of a directive and call the element using `getElementById` instead of `element[0]`, it works perfectly fine.

Why does it fail to render the data once it's in an angularjs directive?

Here's a demo of the working **non angular** version: http://codepen.io/Reklino/pen/PqvyGK/

Here's a demo of the breaking **angular** version: http://codepen.io/Reklino/pen/vOwQzQ/

Comment: I think you need to specify a `template`. I added `template: "<svg width='850' height='200'></svg>"` and it worked. Your button did not work though

Comment: How strange! Do you have any idea why it would need a template? I've created several other d3 charts as angular directives and none of them needed it :/

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with D3 to answer that, sorry!

Comment: also, `template:"<svg></svg>"` works fine too. You should specify the width and height differently.